# how to add signala lib to my android app my develop tool is eclipse

Tags: android, signalr

who can tell me how can I add signalA lib to my android app.

there is a video on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f9ih_M7PC10) which gave a guide to do this.

but the latest signalA-master.zip is different from that files in video.

my develop tool is eclipse.

Comment: extract the .jar and put it to the `/lib` folder of your project, then use it in your code

Comment: there is no .jar file has been found yet...

Answer (score 1):

Download the aar from here.
http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.github.erizet.signala%22%20AND%20a%3A%22signala%22

Rename *.aar to *.zip and extract the jar.

Comment: there is no jar in that aar file.. this is getting stupid how DO you get jar files from signala src?